Does the Next.js middleware compile after the application itself?
In the Next.js docs, we find:

Middleware will be invoked for every route in your project. Given
this, it's crucial to use matchers to precisely target or exclude
specific routes. The following is the execution order:

headers from next.config.js
redirects from next.config.js
Middleware (rewrites, redirects, etc.)
beforeFiles (rewrites) from next.config.js
Filesystem routes (public/, _next/static/, pages/, app/, etc.)
afterFiles (rewrites) from next.config.js
Dynamic Routes (/blog/[slug])
fallback (rewrites) from next.config.js


However, when I compile a Next.js 14 app with middleware, it gives the following console.log output:

✓ Starting...
✓ Ready in 4.5s
○ Compiling / ...
✓ Compiled / in 8s (2873 modules)
console.logs in Server Components are printed
GET / 200 in 9211ms
○ Compiling /src/middleware ...
✓ Compiled /src/middleware in 548ms (228 modules)
console.logs in middleware.ts are printed

Looking at that log output, it seems the Server Component files are evaluated before the middleware.ts file. Is that correct, or am I somehow misinterpreting the logs?
If yes, would that not conflict with the docs excerpt above?

Hi @Berig. Thanks for chiming in. I put them inside the Server Components and both inside and outside middleware.

Another absolutely baffling thing is happening: In the  request sent to a non-auth related middleware function, the Request object contains /api/auth/session in the url and nextUrl.href fields. I tried to uninstall everything related to auth, and removed any code related to it, and still a default function export from the middleware file receives a request polluted with that auth related url pathname. Absolutely bizarre. Any idea if there is something within next.js or related that can touch that request object, before it is passed into the defualt exported function in middleware.ts?

@Bergi I found the reason, it was the matcher. It was set up so the middleware did not run on the page I was loading. Still, found it odd that middleware runs at all then. Do you think it has to do with the fact that other routes are prefetched by Next.js (https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/link#prefetch)? Also still no clue why the url field is polluted with the auth path...

I think I got it. In case other people come across this, check the middleware matcher (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher). Additionally, if you use useSession or similar functions that might call Route Handlers, the middleware will run for those as well. The matcher can be used to exclude the api routes. The middleware request url property refers to the path that is requested.
